# Difference between video call and interactive live stream?

Tags: stream, video-streaming, http-live-streaming, live, agora.io

Difference between video call and interactive live stream in agora?
We want feature like zoom call multiple users should interact in , which service should we choose ?

Answer (score 0):

**Agora Video Call** enables easy and convenient one-to-one or one-to-many calls and supports voice-only and video modes with the Agora RTC SDK.

**Agora Interactive Live Streaming** (Standard) is a product designed for live streaming scenarios featuring “light interaction” between the host and audience. Light interaction, in this case, refers to situations that require a timely exchange of text messages, comments, or virtual gifts, with less reliance on audio or video communication.

Interaction would be required for your use case, so I believe Interactive Live Streaming would be the right choice.
Check out the documentation [here](https://docs.agora.io/en/live-streaming/product_live_standard?platform=Web).

Comment: Hello Aditya,
We are building student teacher communication system Where student can interect with team and also visa versa. Teacher should able to see all student video if they want. 

So which system will be best ?

Agora Video Call OR Agora Interactive Live Streaming

Comment: Since students need to interact with the Teachers, Interactive Live Streaming would be better for your use case.

Comment: We used Live Streaming but it only allow host to present them self , not allow host to see other students in agora. Same like instagram live stream.